# How to minimize child form(not dircet child rather descendent form) from main form

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have following forms herirchy in window  form application,
**(MainForm --> ChildForm ----> DescendentForm)**.
I want to minimize  all forms when Main form is minimized. But 
Main form only minimizes ChildForm  but not the descendentForm.

Please help me out.
I will be grateful.
here is the code to open child form from main form

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        PrintPage objPrintPage = new PrintPage(this);
        objPrintPage.Owner = this;
        objPrintPage.Show();

    }
```

herer is code to open DescendentForm from child form

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            PageSpecified objPageSpecified = new PageSpecified(this);
            objPageSpecified.Owner = this;
            objPageSpecified.Show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to make any assumptions without seeing your application code. How exactly you're creating, showing and minimizing your forms?

Comment: Dear Andy Komeyev
I have added code in the question.

Comment: Dear @AndyKorneyev I have added the code in the question.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem? I can't imagine how MDI inside MDI looks like and what is the problem with minimizing.

Comment: Dear @Sinatr sorry i can't post image :( I am new at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If we you want to minimize the child (which is not direct descendent) you have to declare the owner of DescendentForm to Main form
so in place of 
`objPageSpecified.Owner = this;
you have to write:

```
objPageSpecified.Owner = this.Owner;


  PageSpecified objPageSpecified = new PageSpecified(this);
        objPageSpecified.Owner = this.Owner;
        objPageSpecified.Show();
```